# jdbctemplate postgres json

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbctemplate, jsonb

***Hi, please suggest me what can i do?***
I'm using postgres and i have 2 fields table:

- -id(bigint)
- -attributes(jsonb)

attributes structure = { id: "..." , name: ".."}

---

### I need to check if there's an object with the same id in json

so i have a method:

```
`public Optional<Long> getIdByAtlasId(Long atlasId) {
            String sql = "SELECT id FROM dictionary WHERE attributes -> 'attributes' ->> 'id' = :atlas_id";
            try {
                return Optional.ofNullable(jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql, Collections.singletonMap("atlasId", atlasId),Long.class));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return Optional.empty();
            }
        }`
```

*and it always return null*, thought I have this ids in table, so at first i decided to try this query in db :
`SELECT id FROM dictionary WHERE attributes ->> 'id' = 85`

and it gives "operator does not exist: text = integer".
The next attempt was:

`SELECT id FROM dictionary WHERE attributes ->> 'id' = '85'`

and it returns id
In this case, i decided to pass string parameter to my method:

`jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql, Collections.singletonMap("atlasId", atlasId.toString()),Long.class)`

*but it still returns null.*

### **Thank you in advance,any help is appreciated**